# Any gotchas moving Azure SQL Database to Serverless?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I wanted to turn on autoscaling for an Azure SQL Database. That option is not available for ASD, unless you either use elastic pools or turn on Serverless database. The serverless database sounds terrific, but what the downsides or gotchas to this.

Comment: Hi Bryan Schmiedeler, If my answer is helpful for you, can you please mark it as answer? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this is very helpful.

Comment: For one thing, serverless definitely calls for a **retrying** `ExecutionStrategy`, when using Entity Framework. You see, the serverless database can be paused (by default after an hour of inactivity), in which case the first query against it will wake it and fail. A retrying strategy protects your code against noticing this - although it will still take about a minute to get a result from such a retrying query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reference here: [Comparison with provisioned compute tier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-serverless#comparison-with-provisioned-compute-tier):

The following table summarizes distinctions between the serverless compute tier and the provisioned compute tier:

[image]

This table can show you  the downsides or gotchas to Serverless database.

For more details about Serverless, ref: [Azure SQL Database serverless](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-serverless).

Hope this helps.

Comment: One gotcha that got me - memory optimized object are not compatible